# Renaming columns within a frequency dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I calculated a frequency dataframe. However I would need rename the first column (there is no name, as shown below).

```
                    Frequency
Trump won election 46
US working vaccine  45
seqirus coronavirus vitamine    45
... ...
Apple closed shops  1
still water helps   1
```

created by

```
freq = sum(sparse_matrix).toarray()[0]
df=pd.DataFrame(freq, index=word_vectorizer.get_feature_names(), columns=['Frequency'])
df=df.sort_values(by='Frequency', ascending=False)
```

I have tried with

```
df = df.rename(columns={'index':'Words'})
```

But nothing has changed. My expected output would be:

```
Words                  Frequency
Trump won election 46
US working vaccine  45
seqirus coronavirus vitamine    45
... ...
Apple closed shops  1
still water helps   1
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: `df.rename_axis('Words')`?

Comment: 'Words' is associated with the name of the index, not columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `rename` to `rename_axis`

```
df = df.rename_axis('Words')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
df.index.names = ['Words']
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Mayank Porwal. Would it be the same in case I would need to edit more columns?

Comment: No, this only works for the index. For renaming other columns, you need to use `rename` command.